# Why aren't my links turning into actual hyperlinks?

Tags: ms-word

This recently started happening in my word files and I have no idea why. It happens even in a new document. I'll type in a link and instead of it actually turning into a clickable link, I get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to **Word Options**
- Select **Advanced** tab
- Scroll down to **Show Document Context** section
- Make sure that "**Show fields codes instead of their values**" is
  unchecked